# How can I re-open a Maven project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven

I was working on a Maven project. I closed Eclipse, and now I don't know how to re-open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to File > Import then select Maven and Existing Maven Projects. Select the folder that contains the `pom.xml` file.

[image: importing maven projects]